# RuntimeException is not displaying the error message in postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot restful API every time I try

```
if(userRepository.findByEmail != null) Throw new RuntimeException("This email already exists");
```

I don't get the message back I only get the error with an empty message in postman instead I get only inside spring boot command the message I passed in RuntimeException.

Comment: Use Spring 'Response Entity' in API calls or service calls. Response entity represents the response, header and HTTP status codes. By doing this, you can see the exceptions in postman. Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: I edited, please check

Comment: Have exactly same problem. Any solution to this?

Comment: Still the same not changed I didn't get any help at all

Answer (score 12):

They've changed this in Spring 2.3.0, to see the error message through postman you need to add `server.error.include-message=always` in your properties file (application.properties)

Comment: Why would they do this seriously ? i spent 2 hours of my life searching for this answer, I'am so mad rn but thanks for the answer buddy